# String.split's weird behaviour dealing with spaces and tabs

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string consisting of tabs and spaces and some arbitrary characters. The string below is made up of `space space tab tab 1 space tab -2 tab space + space`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

String[] s = "          1   -2   + ".split("[\\s]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Running split with regex `[\s+]` one would expect to get `[1, -2, +]`, however the returned array I get on my machine (OS X, JDK1.6.0_37) is `[, 1, -2, +]`.

It turns out the first element is simply "blank" (`s[0].equals("")` returns `true`) and so it should have been matched by `\s`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It makes sense to me - and imagine if you had a CSV file where the first row was ",foo,bar" - wouldn't that naturally suggest there were three columns, with the first value being empty?

Comment: No need for the character class, `\s+` will work equally well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If while splitting your string, the first character of the string is amongst the delimiter, then the first element of the generated array is always an `empty string`.

Take it this way, your string always starts with an `empty string`. So, your delimiter - `\s+` will be divide `"    a"` string(note the leading whitespace) in two parts, first before `\s+` which is *empty string* `""`, and one after it, which is `a`.

So, the output you got is obvious.

> It turns out the first element is simply "blank" (s[0].equals("")
>   returns true) and so it should have been matched by \s.

No it shouldn't have been. A space is not an empty string. There is difference between them.

Comment: Right, and that it makes sense one can see with split by "," on data like ",2,3,4" where obviously the first field is empty.

Comment: @Smit. Lol. Nope ;) I'm Vampire. :D

Comment: Thanks, I guess it makes sense. Any clever way of rewriting it so that the first empty char doesn't get included? I.e. I only want `[1, -2, +]`

Comment: @0sh.. You can trim the string first, and then apply the split. This will remove the delimiter from the beginning, thus not giving you an empty element in the array.